# sql combining 2 columns sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm a bit rusty on my SQL and Access so just wanted some help.

I have a set of data like the below in Access

```
C1 C2 C3 
1  A  C
2  B  D
3  B  E
```

From this data I wanted run a SQL query that will combine columns 2 and 3 but also retain the information in column 1 alongside it. I've illustrated this below

```
C1 C2
1  A 
2  B
3  B
1  C
2  D
3  E
```

I've run a sql query using a union syntax to combine columns 1 and 2 already but can't figure out how to include the column 1 data as well.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Shan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know access but if it supports union something like:

```
select c1, c2 as c2 from T
union all
select c1, c3 as c2 from T
```

should work. If c2 and c3 always differ, or if you are not interested in duplicates `union` can be used instead of `union all`